# Moodle H5P file or any content above 20 MB not able to upload

Tags: php, linux, moodle, system-administration

**Overview:** We have been using our moodle for some time and have been using it to create content for the university. But we have encountered an issue, where we cannot upload the content on moodle above 20MB, even after we have already allowed it on our system. We keep getting the below upload sign. We are facing the same issue for any file/content which is more than 20MB of size

[Moodle Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyp4I.jpg)

**Reproduce:** We have even tried to resolve this issue by uploading it from a different network, and checked the user permission but were not able to resolve it.

Below,  I have also attached the phpinfo.php where we have already allowed more than 3gb of space.

[Moodle PHPinfo.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yjui.png)

You can find more information on this moodle forum about our issue, which we have posted here: https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=436705

The maximum upload size is also set up to 2GB in Moodle Site Administration settings.
[Site Administration Settings of Moodle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TZU0.png)

Comment: Which web server software are you using? Says right below the site administration settings you need both PHP and the web server to be loosened size-wise, have you taken a look into that?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by the web server. Can you pls share where shall I look for the settings?

Comment: The webserver has its own limit, and it comes _before_ PHP

Comment: I have tried it on both Firefox, Brave and Chrome all of them are showing the same thing.

Comment: This is the permission which I have set to the /var/www/moodledata. drwxrwx--- 13 www-data www-data 4096 Jul 29 18:17 /var/www/moodledata/

Comment: By web server software I mean the layer that handles your HTTP(s) requests, i.e.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server . The most common ones would be apache/nginx and as pointed out those have limits, in their .conf files, of their own you need to look into.

Comment: We are using Proxmos to deploy it and shall I restart the promos? Do Moodle uses apache/nginx for their projects. Like any other thing which can help in resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch the debugging level to developer, this should give you a full error message. If its a production site, then switch it on briefly, try the upload, then switch it back to whatever it was before. Then copy and paste the error message - if there is one

Site administration > Development > Debugging

http://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Debugging

There are also file size restrictions at the course level and the activity level. Check in the course settings and activity settings that there isn't a limit.

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Administration_FAQ#How_do_the_limits_on_uploaded_files_work.3F

It's also possible that the server is timing out. You might need to increase the PHP value for `max_execution_time`

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Administration_FAQ#How_to_change_the_maximum_execution_time_for_file_uploads

Also, in case you missed it, you usually need to restart the web server for the changes to the PHP settings to take effect

Comment: Hi Russel, I have enabled the debugging, but it is not throwing any error where shall I look for the error? I have also checked the course setting it is allowing a 2GB file of content. Where Can I find .php.ini file what is the location and shall I restart the web server like I am using Proxmos in my case, so shall I restart the container containing moodle application on Proxmos.